# Core Data - Simple Query Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I am working on a simple Core Data app.  I have two classes: `Client` and `Home`.  There is a one-to-many relationship between Clients and Homes (i.e., a Client can have many Homes.  Among other attributes, the `Home` class has one called `purchaseDate`.

I am trying to write two methods on the `Client` class: `-homesByDate` and -`firstHome`.  `-homesByDate` should return either an NSArray or NSSet of the client's homes sorted by `purchaseDate`.  `-firstHome` should return just the first home that the client purchased.

I know that given a Client, I can use `self.homes` to access all of the client's homes, but how do I implement the methods above?  Does this involve applying some sort of an NSPredicate?

Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seek `NSSortDescriptor`!

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"purchaseDate" ascending:YES];
//Obtain arrayOfHomes however you'd like
homesByDate = [arrayOfHomes sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
firstHome = [homesByDate objectAtIndex:0];
```

I should also point out that it's common to let NSArrayController do the sorting for you (if, for example, `homesByDate` is just for display in a table view or something). You can use `setSortDescriptors` or use bindings. (This is also handy if you want the user to be able to choose from several orders.)